# Where is global variables like $_GLOBAL , $_POST etc stored?

Tags: php, c, memory-management, global-variables

When i attended an interview, the interviewer asked me this question. Which memory they are using heap , stack etc. I googled it but i didn't get any clear answer.

Comment: Do you know what a stack / heap is? I would start there. Also are you sure they knew what they were talking about?

Comment: This question only makes sense if you are planning to work as a PHP core developer, but in that case the question should be tagged with `C` too…

Comment: I've never once heard of anyone care that much about memory management when developing in PHP (as opposed to developing PHP itself)... Look into the Zend memory manager

Comment: @feeela i tagged C also.

Comment: @PeeHaa i know basic concepts of stack and heap.

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422605/how-exactly-is-php-creating-superglobal-post-get-cookie-and-request The source is here: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php_variables.c#L708

Comment: @feeela but i need to know for global variables and others how memory is allocated and which memory they are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values of `$_POST` internally are created inside [`php_auto_globals_create_post()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/main/php_variables.c#673) and made available via `PG(http_globals)[TRACK_VARS_POST]`, which is just a way to reference [`http_globals`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/main/php_globals.h#111).

The definition of aforementioned `http_globals` tells us that it's an array of [`zval *`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend.h#_zval_struct) elements, one for each `$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_COOKIE`, etc. (arrays are also stored inside a `zval` container).

Allocating a `zval` is done via [`ALLOC_ZVAL()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_alloc.h#165), which calls the following functions:

1. [`_emalloc()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_alloc.c#2418)
2. [`_malloc()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_alloc.c#2685)

The `malloc()` function allocates memory on the heap, so therefore the answer is **heap**.

Comment: Jack i'm getting confused now, since php is developed in c what @KepaniHaole told would be correct right?

Comment: @Pramod He's referring to global variables in C itself; I'm referring to how global variables *in PHP* are stored.

Answer (score 7):

Well, since you tagged `C`, I'll start with that.

In the C runtime, global variables are stored in one of two places; the data segment or the BSS segment.
The way you determine which one a particular variable belongs to is whether or not it is initialized.

***Initialized*** global (and static) variables go inside the ***data segment***.

***Uninitialized*** global (and static) variables go inside the ***BSS segment***.

Visually, the entire runtime looks like this:

```
 _______
|  Text |
|_______|
|  Data |   <-- Initialized globals / statics
|_______|
|  BSS  |   <-- Uninitialized globals / statics (basically a bunch of 0s)
|_______|
|       |
| Stack |
|_______|
|       |
|  Heap |
|_______|
```

Unlike variables on the ***stack*** and the ***heap***, which are created at runtime, global variables exist as part of your program's executable image file (`a.out`, `foobar.exe`).

Comment: thanks, Now i got some idea of it. But still i have doubt like they are managed in php..