# In PHP where the globally declared variables stored?

Tags: php, memory-management, operating-system

where the globally declared PHP variables are stored in memory?
if we declare a variable $test = 0; outside function.

where this variable and values are stored in the memory. There are memories like heap , stack, code segment and data segment associated with each prograrm. In PHP, how the memory is managed for a PHP program?.. how the variables are handled in PHP?...

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to know this? Generally, any variable you declare will be stored as data, whether it's a global variable or not

Comment: it was an interview question asked to me. The question is 'Where the global variables are stored while executing a php program?'

Comment: Today this interview question is quite popular: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488318/where-is-global-variables-like-global-post-etc-stored

Comment: I checked above shown link. My doubt is memory allocation for php and c are same ?

Comment: Given that PHP is actually written in C, then it uses C dynamic memory allocation for variables internally

Answer (score 0):

global variables are stored in the $GLOBALS associative array.

if you do something like:

```
$var="global";

function foo(){
    $var="local";
    echo $GLOBALS['var'];
    echo $var;
}
```

It will print "global" and then "local".

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, OP wants to know how PHP _internally_ handles global variables

Comment: Yes. I want to know how the variable are handled internally in PHP. Mr. Damien Pirsy is correct

Comment: oh, sry then for my answer ^^'